# Enable opcache from htacces not from .ini file

Tags: opcache

I set opcache.enable=0 in opcache.ini

Now I want to enable opcache from my htaccess file using

php_flag opcache.enable On

But it is not working

Is there any way, I disable opcache in opcache.ini, and enable in my application's htacces file.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The simple reply here is that you can't *enable*.  OPcache is a zend_extension and as such can only be enabled at a system level. However, there is a simple wrinkle here in the opcache.enable is a **PHP_INI_ALL** directive and can be set to 0 anywhere either at a directory or program context.  So having `opcache.enable=1` in the system configuration and then setting

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

should work, and this will disable caching for the scope of that request

Also read up on the directive `opcache.blacklist_filename` (which is a bit of a misnomer, BTW).  This allows you to define files and file hierarchies that are *not* to be cached (but once blacklisted you can't then create exceptions or unblacklist files at runtime.

Also since the enable is a **PHP_INI_ALL** directive, there is nothing stopping you adding a bit of code logic disable caching for the scope of that request in  an `auto_prepend_file` included script instead of using an htaccess `php_flag` directive, but not that once disabled, you then can't re-enable it, so you can only use the blacklist to control caching at a file level.